# Pirkei Avos on shabbos during mincha?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, synagogue, tehilim-psalms, pirke-avot-ethicsof

It seems clear from the Rama, MB, and other sources (as well as from most printed siddurim) that Pirkei Avos is said in the synagogue at Shabbos Mincha as part of the tefillah in the summer months, and Barchi Nafshi in the winter. Are there any synagogues (other than yekke shuls) that still follow this? It seems from most siddurim that it is done before Aleinu (I also have seen this done at Breuer's, which is generally a good source for minhagim) so I'm specifically interested if there are other shuls that still do it this way?

Comment: I know many people who do this individually, and virtually every Siddur I've ever seen has it printed there. Some shuls do it as a learning program, although I've never been to a shul that does it formally as part of the Tefillah.

Comment: aaron, a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your interesting questions about communal practices! I look forward to seeing you around more. I edited out the part that was asking for people to affirm your recommendation for what communities ought to do, since that part seemed to me to ["solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#close). If there's something more objective that you want to add to the question, feel free to [edit] it in.

Comment: You could improve this question by [edit]ing in citations for the sources you mention.

Answer (score 4):

The [Great Synagogue of Rome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aRoma-sinagoga.jpg) still says Pirkei Avot between Mincha and Maariv as a communal liturgical recitation in the summer. Source: I was there once.

In light of edits to question: They did not do it before Aleinu IIRC, but they did do it before they broke for Seudah Shelishit, so I'd say it was still part of the general Mincha service and not part of the Maariv service.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [Pirkei Avos](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/680360/jewish/What-Is-Ethics-of-Our-Fathers.htm):

> Many (including Chabad) continue this chapter-a-week regimen throughout the summer months, until Rosh Hashanah.

Comment: Do they do this as a communal recitation, or people do it themselves once a week?

Comment: Between Mincha and Maariv at shul

Comment: They are not recited out loud in unison. Chassidim sit together and say the weekly chapter before beginning a Seder Niggunim and the recitation of a Maamar.

Comment: Minhag Ashkenaz was not necessarily to recite it out loud (though this is the Sephardi custom, and seems to also be the Italian custom), it was to recite it quietly just like Ashkenazim recite most other parts of the davening, but as part of the tefillah, before Aleinu (and I think followed by Kaddish). This gives it more prominence as part of the davening (just like by Sfiras Haomer, which is said in most places before Aleinu), rather than something people say afterward. Does chabad recite it before Aleinu, or after?

Comment: @aaron, if your question is about saying it before "_Alenu_" specifically, then you should edit that into your question. I for one certainly didn't understand that.