# Discrepancies in the Forty-Eight Qualities of Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, pirke-avot-ethicsof

The "[sixth chapter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84858/who-added-the-sixth-chapter-of-avot)" of Avot lists forty-eight qualities with which Torah is acquired.

> גדולה תורה יותר מן הכהונה ומן המלכות, שהמלכות נקנית בשלשים מעלות,
>   והכהנה בעשרים וארבע, והתורה נקנית בארבעים ושמונה דברים, ואלו הן:
>   בתלמוד, בשמיעת האזן, בעריכת שפתים, בבינת הלב, באימה, ביראה, בענוה,
>   בשמחה, בטהרה, בשמוש חכמים, בדקדוק חברים, בפלפול התלמידים, בישוב,
>   במקרא, במשנה, במעוט סחורה, במעוט דרך ארץ, במעוט תענוג, במעוט שנה,
>   במעוט שיחה, במעוט שחוק, בארך אפים, בלב טוב, באמונת חכמים, בקבלת
>   היסורין, המכיר את מקומו, והשמח בחלקו, והעושה סיג לדבריו, ואינו מחזיק
>   טובה לעצמו, אהוב, אוהב את המקום, אוהב את הבריות, אוהב את הצדקות, אוהב
>   את המישרים, אוהב את התוכחות, ומתרחק מן הכבוד, ולא מגיס לבו בתלמודו,
>   ואינו שמח בהוראה, נושא בעל עם חברו, ומכריעו לכף זכות, ומעמידו על האמת,
>   ומעמידו על השלום, ומתישב לבו בתלמודו, שואל ומשיב, שומע ומוסיף, הלומד
>   על מנת ללמד והלומד על מנת לעשות, המחכים את רבו, והמכון את שמועתו,
>   והאומר דבר בשם אומרו
>
> *Greater is Torah than priesthood and kingship, for kingship is
>   obtained with thirty levels, and priesthood with twenty-four, and
>   Torah is obtained with forty-eight things. And these are them:
>   learning, listening of the ear, preparation of speech, understanding
>   of the heart, intellect of the heart, reverence, awe, humility,
>   happiness, purity, service of sages, care of friends, debate of the
>   students, clarification, scripture, mishnah, minimization of
>   merchandise, minimization of worldly occupation, minimization of
>   pleasure, minimization of sleep, minimization of conversation,
>   minimization of laughter, patience, generosity, trust of the sages,
>   acceptance of afflictions, knowing one's place, gladness in one's
>   portion, erection of a fence to one's words, lack of
>   self-aggrandizement, lovableness, love of God, love of the creatures,
>   love of the righteous, love of the upright, love of rebuke, distancing
>   from honor, lack of arrogance in learning, lack of joy in issuing
>   legal decisions, lifting of a burden with one's friend, judging him
>   with the benefit of the doubt, placing him with the truth, placing him
>   with peace, deliberation in study, questioning and responding, hearing
>   and adding, learning in order to teach and learning in order to act,
>   making one's master wiser, focusing one's teaching, saying [a thing]
>   in the name of the one who said it.*

Are there any other sources, earlier in composition than this version, which list the qualities any differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commonly known by their appearance in the “sixth chapter” of Avot, this list of virtuous attainments of Torah, along with the rest of the chapter, are actually an emended version of Baraitot from earlier sources, which were supplemented to the weekly Avot study cycle [in the Geonic period](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42696&st=&pgnum=67) to provide sufficient reading material for a six-week Shabbat learning session between Pesach and Shavuot. The version which appears in most Siddurim actually differs substantially from earlier versions of the text found in Talmudic and post-Talmudic manuscripts.

There are four ways in which the versions differentiate from each other:

- Content - Each list offers its' own unique qualities (some of which may be due to textual variances over time and transcription; I merely present the facts as they are).
- Order - Even when listing similar qualities, the order differs substantially from list to list. This can be significant for those who attempt to glean insight into a particular progression that the list sketches for the reader.
- Count - Although each version purports to contain forty-eight qualities, one must strain to actually find that number of qualities in each list. I have been most liberal in dividing out qualities maximally, yet three versions still fall short (with Midrash Mishlei coming in at just 29).
- Nature of these qualities - Some versions refer to them as קנינים, acquisitions, while others refer to them as מעלות, virtues. Some include a descriptive term דברים, while others do not.

I have highlighted qualities which are unique to each version in the texts provided below.

What appears to be the earliest rendition of this Baraita can be found in the [8th chapter of Mesechet Kallah Rabbati](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22666&st=&pgnum=48), an early anthology of Baraitot with Talmudic discussions which can usually be found printed after Mesechet Avodah Zara. Some editions have this as the 6th or 7th chapter:

> גדולה תורה מן הכהונה ומן המלכות, שהמלכות בשלשים מעלות, וכהונה בעשרים
>   וארבעה, והתורה בארבעים ושמונה **דברים**: בישיבה, במקרא, בדרך ארץ, במיעוט
>   שינה, **במיעוט שיחה**, במיעוט סחורה,במיעוט שחוק, במיעוט תענוג, במיעוט דרך
>   ארץ, בארך אפים, ולב טוב, באמונת חכמים, ובקבלת היסורין בתלמוד, בשמיעת
>   אזן, בעריכת שפתים, בבינת הלב, בשכלות הלב, **בקימה**, ביראה, בחכמה, בענוה,
>   בשמוש חכמים, ובדקדוק חברים, ובפלפול התלמידים, המכיר את מקומו, השמח
>   בחלקו, העושה סיג לדבריו, ואין מחזיק טובה לעצמו, ואוהב את המקום, אוהב
>   את התוכחות, אוהב את הצדקות, אוהב את המישרים, מתרחק מן הכבוד, ולא רודף
>   אחר הכבוד, ולא מגיס לבו בתלמודו, ולא שמח בהוראה, הנושא בעול עם חברו,
>   והמכריעו לכף זכות, מעמידו על האמת, מעמידו על השלום, מתישב בתלמודו,
>   שואל ומשיב, שומע ומוסיף, המחכם את רבו, המכוין את שמועתו, והאומר דבר
>   בשם אומרו

[Midrash Mishlei](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12401-proverbs-midrash-to), an exegetical commentary on the book of Proverbs written before the beginning of the 11th century (as quoted by R. Chananel; Buber finds content references going back to the 8th century), records a version of the forty-eight qualities ([Parasha 19:14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14102&st=&pgnum=83)) which differs substantially from all other authoritative versions of the text. Of significance is this work being the only one which attributes specific authorship to this Baraita - namely, R. Yishmael.

> **אמר ר' ישמעאל**: גדולה היא התורה **שהיא גדולה יותר** מן הכהונה ומן המלכות,
>   שהמלכות נקנית בשלשים מעלות, והכהונה בעשרים וארבע, והתורה **נקנית** בארבעים
>   ושמונה דברים, **ואלו הן**: בישוב הלב, בשמיעת האוזן, בעריכות שפתים, **ובהטבת**
>   **פנים**, ולב טוב, **בדעה**, ובחכמה, מכיר את מקומו, **וקונה לו חבר, ומדקדק**
>   **בתלמודו**, **ומעין בשמועתו, ואומר על הטמא טמא, ועל הטהור טהור, ועל הן הן**,
>   **ועל לאו לאו**, ואומר דבר בשם אומרו, ונושא בעול עם חבירו, ומכריעו לכף
>   זכות, **ומקבל פני חכמים**, **ואוהב פלפול חכמים**, **ושמח בתלמודו**, **ואין גס לבו**
>   **בהוראה**, **ואין מורה הלכה בפני רבי, ולא יושב במקום מי שהוא גדול ממנו**,
>   ואוהב את הבריות, ואוהב את התוכחות, **ומודה על האמת, ונושא ונותן בשמועתו**,
>   **ומייסר בנו לתלמוד תורה**

[Seder Eliyahu Zuta](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2590&st=&pgnum=287), in [chapter 17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39067&st=&pgnum=44) (which itself is a supplementary addition to the book proper) records a similar formulation but with significant differences. This Midrashic work dates back to at least 1136 CE, and shares the name of an earlier work written by R. Anan containing teachings from Eliyahu HaNavi (Cf. B. Ketuvot 106a).

> גדולה תורה מן הכהונה ומן המלכות, שהמלכות בשלשים מעלות, וכהונה בעשרים
>   וארבע, והתורה **נקנית** בארבעים ושמונה **דברים**, **ואלו הן**: בתלמוד, בשמיעת
>   האוזן, בעריכת שפתיים, **בבינת שפתיים**, בבינת הלב, **בשכל**, באימה, ויראה,
>   בענוה, בשמחה, בשימוש חכמים, **בדיבוק חברים**, בישיבה, במקרא, ובמשנה, בדרך
>   ארץ, במיעוט שינה, במיעוט תענוג, במיעוט דרך ארץ, במיעוט סחורה, בארך
>   אפים, בלב טוב, באמונת חכמים, ובקבלת היסורין, והמכיר את מקומו, והשמח
>   בחלקו, והעושה סייג לדבריו, ואינו מחזיק טובה לעצמו, אוהב את המקום, אוהב
>   את הבריות, אוהב את התוכחות, אוהב את המישרים, ומתרחק מן הכבוד, ואינו
>   רודף אחר הכבוד, ואינו מגיס לבו בלימודו, ואינו שמח בהוראה, הנושא בעול
>   עם חבירו, ומכריעו לכף זכות, ומעמידו על האמת ועל השלום, ומתישב בלמודו,
>   שואל ומשיב, הלומד על מנת ללמד, והלומד על מנת לעשות, והמחכים את רבו,
>   והמכוון את שמועתו, והאומר דבר בשם אומרו

As regarding the “sixth chapter” of Avot itself, the text of this chapter, also known as Perek Kinyan Torah, was critically evaluated by [Michael Higger](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%92%D7%A8) (in [Chorev II:2, 1936](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23221&st=&pgnum=167)) based primarily on three early manuscripts of the text. This, too, differs substantially from the popular version found in Siddurim today.

> גדולה תורה מן הכהונה ומן המלכות, שהמלכות בשלשים מעלות, והכהונה בעשרים
>   וארבעה מעלות, ותורה **נקנית** בארבעים ושמונה **מעלות**: בישוב, במקרא, במשנה,
>   בתלמוד, בדרך ארץ, במיעוט שינה, במיעוט סחורה, במיעוט שחוק, במיעוט
>   תענוג, במיעוט דרך ארץ, בארך אפים, בלב טוב, **באומנות חכמים**, ובקבלת
>   יסורין, בשמיעת האוזן, בעריכות שפתים, בבינת הלב, בשכלות הלב, באימה,
>   ביראה, בחכמה, בענוה, בשמחה, בשמוש חכמים, **בדבוק התלמידים**, ובפלפול
>   התלמידים, המכיר את מקומו, השמח בחלקו, והעושה סיג לדברו, ואינו מחזיק
>   טובה לעצמו, אוהב את המקום, אוהב את הבריות, אוהב את הצדקות, אוהב את
>   התוכחות, אוהב את המישרים, ומתרחק מן הכיבוד, ולא רודף אחר הכבוד, ולא
>   מגיס לבו בתלמוד, ולא שמח בהוראה, הנושא בעול עם חבירו, ומכריעו לזכות,
>   ומעמידו על השלום, המתישב בתלמודו, ושואל ומשיב, שומע ומוסיף, **ואינו נכנס**
>   **לתוך דברי חבירו**, **המחכה את רבו**, והמכוין את שמועתו, והאומר דבר בשם אומרו

There are also significant differences in the closing words of each version, but that goes beyond the scope of this question.

In conclusion, each of the versions has some qualities which are unique to its’ version, while sharing others in common with other versions. As well, there are minor textual variations between each version, including additional or missing Vav’s and spelling differences, which can impact the meaning and grammatical breakdown of the list.